# without insert function can we do insert new element in array index using python programming?

Tags: python, data-structures

Normally we insert the new element in an array but without the insert function how can we do it?
When I am trying to do code in python it giving so much error related to array index

Comment: If you have a specific example of some code that you've tried and the error message that was shown, it will be much easier to provide a useful answer

Comment: Edit the question to show the problem you're having, don't put code in comments.

Comment: `int main() { int arr[size] = {1, 20, 5, 78, 30}; int element, pos, i; printf("Enter position and element\n"); scanf("%d%d",&pos,&element); if(pos <= size && pos >= 0) { for(i = size; i > pos; i--) arr[i] = arr[i-1]; arr[pos] = element; for(i = 0; i <= size; i++) printf("%d ", arr[i]); } else printf("Invalid Position\n"); return 0; }`

Comment: @RR_S That's C, not Python.

Comment: @RR_S that si not python. That looks to be C. In any case, don't post code in the comments. Edit your question to make it complete. Assuming you *do* mean python, you are going to have to be specific about whatever artificial constraints you have because we cannot guess what you mean

Comment: @RR_S you can't translate that code to python (or most other memory-safe languages though those with sparse arrays will often just expand the array to fit OOB indices) because python will not let you index out of initialised bounds. Though it's essentially what `list.insert` will do internally, after having checked that the allocated space is sufficient.

Comment: @Masklinn yes, internally, Pyhton list objects are array-lists, so there is some internal, overallocated buffer. If there is still space, it simply shifts everything to the right of the index by one, and inserts the new item. If there isn't, it re-allocates the buffer, then inserts everything as you need it. Perhaps doing something like that is what the OP means? It isn't at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with slice assignment.

```
l.insert(i, new_element)
```

can be done using

```
l[i:i] = [new_element]
```

Comment: You could also append() the new element, then sift it down to its correct position by swapping. Probably not as good as you need `n = len - i` swaps but still an option.

Comment: Yes, @Masklinn ur right but I   want to do code without append and insert function ...how can we do?

Comment: Barmar shows how to do it. Seems rather odd though, there's no situation where you won't have append and insert.

Comment: I suspect if the OP can't use `l.insert(i, new_element)` then `l[i:i] = [new_element]` will be agains the spirit of whatever they are doing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What do you think *would* be in the spirit?

Comment: I *imagine* that it would be something like you would have to do with a primitive array in C. But I can only guess. I hate these questions that introduce artificial limitations without properly specifying what's allowed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga or why the limitations are there in the first place e.g. is it a thought exercise, a schools exercise, or are there actual constraints (I can imagine a restricted environment where function / method calls are forbidden and OP wants to know if it's still possible to extend lists, in which case Barmar's answer would be suitable, though why you'd care about extending lists but not updating them in-place I couldn't say).